# Develop for iphone 5 on xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, iphone-5

I'm developing an app using xcode 4.2. I'm using and older Mac and I am unable to upgrade to a newer version of xcode or iOS. Is there a way I can make my application compatible with iPhone 5? It's a very basic app but all I need to do is stretch the screen to fit iphone 5. If not, how will the display be effected? Will it still be the same resolution size as iPhone 4 but just on the 5's larger screen - like a "letterbox" effect?

Comment: I don't think you can.  You need to get a version of Xcode that supports iOS 6, which means you need a dev environment running Lion+.

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe - I suspected this may be the case but was hoping there would be some sort of work around. Will my app still be displayed on iPhone 5 or will it be rejected by Apple do you know? Even if I can get it on the iStore and then work on optimising it for the iPhone 5 when I get my hands on Lion+ later it will be OK.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, however you're going to want to test it on a 4-inch display before submitting it.  When developing for Apple devices, they expect you to keep up with Hardware and O/S, which I know isn't possible/convenient for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what if you can't upgrade your xcode or ios we are here to help you ;)

put this code on you appdelegate.h

#define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f

and use the below condition where you set the frame with coding

```
if(IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568)
{
    tbl.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 300, 381);
}
else
{
    tbl.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 300, 293);
}
```

take a look at the difference of both the height is 88 so you need to add 88 on height of you every component you set frame with coding thats how you can manage your app compatible with iPhone5.

Comment: Thanks for that eptdeveloper. I will definitely be implementing this into my project. I suspected there was a workaround. Thanks a million again